# Is it possible to call Pyright from code (as an API)?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

It seems that [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) (the Python type checker made by Microsoft) can only be used as a command line tool or from VS Code. But is it possible to call pyright from code (as an API)?

For example, mypy [supports](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#integrating-mypy-into-another-python-application) usage like:

```py
import sys
from mypy import api

result = api.run("your code")
```

Comment: have you tried using `subprocess` to call the cli?

Comment: Why would you want to? That is, your question sounds like a typical "XY Problem", where you probably want to do this for some reason, when there's a better way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Unlike Python-based mypy, Pyright is written in TypeScript, so you can't directly integrate Pyright in Python code without using the CLI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @Grismar said, this might be an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... if not, here is a general solution:

```py
import subprocess

command = ['pyright', 'path/to/your/file.py']
result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
output = result.stdout

print(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

also you can use this solution:

```py
import subprocess


try:
    command = ['pyright', 'path/to/your/file.py']
    result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
    if result.returncode !=0:
        print(f'Return Code Not Zero : {result.returncode}')
        print(f'Stderror : {result.stderr}')
    output = result.stdout
    print(f'Stdout :{output}')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"[CalledProcessError]: {e}")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(f"[FileNotFoundError]: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"[Other error occurred]: {e}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).